Pytorch ViT inference on GPU A100 is very slow
I'm using a GPU server which has 4 A100 chips.
I'm studying how to use ViT (in timm).
My local GPU is a GTX 1650 Super but it is faster than a A100.
The A100 takes almost 1 hour to finish the inference.
I run the python file by
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICE=$UUID python myfile.py

# Load a pre-trained Vision Transformer model
model = timm.create_model('vit_base_patch16_224', pretrained=True)
model.eval()  # Set the model to evaluation mode

# Ensure the model is on the correct device
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
torch.cuda.empty_cache()
model.to(device)

# Define the ImageNet transforms, these should match the pre-training regime
imagenet_transforms = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize(256),
    transforms.CenterCrop(224),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]),
])

# Setup DataLoader for ImageNet validation set
imagenet_val = datasets.ImageFolder('/home/shared/Imagenet_data/val', transform=imagenet_transforms)
val_loader = DataLoader(imagenet_val, batch_size=256, shuffle=False)

def evaluate_accuracy(model, data_loader):
    model.eval()
    correct = 0
    total = 0

    with torch.no_grad():
        for images, labels in tqdm(data_loader):
            images, labels = images.to(device), labels.to(device)
            outputs = model(images)
            _, predicted = outputs.max(1)
            correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()
            total += labels.size(0)

    accuracy = 100 * correct / total
    return accuracy

accuracy = evaluate_accuracy(model, val_loader)
print(f"Accuracy on ImageNet validation set: {accuracy:.2f}%")

I can't find the reason why it is too slow.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
I took my model and data on device(cuda) and there are 4 GPUs in the server via MIG. I use conda for the virtual environment.
I tried putting os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]=$UUID in the code but it didn't work.
print(device) yields cuda.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. Copy the actual text into a code block instead.

"CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICE=$UUID python myfile.py" it should be CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES ("S" at the end) as you later write yourself. Is that only a typo in the question or did you also use that wrong environment variable name in practice?

I found there is no num_workers in dataloader...default = 0
val_loader = DataLoader(imagenet_val, batch_size=256, shuffle=False, num_workers=16)
works! thanks

It was a typo in question CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES is applied. :)
